# API-only app in rails with grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, grape-api

i have a question regarding Grape for building an API-only rails app. As I read in the github docs, Grape can be mounted as an API for an existing rails app. Is it possible to write a API-only app with it? Am I right, that I don't need rails controllers any longer when using Grape?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

Also, if I am not mistaken, you don't even need Rails at all. Grape is a micro-framework which can run standalone. If you have plans to expand however and incorporate active-record/model etc than you could mount Grape and expand at your own pace.

Comment: yeah i'm using active record and some other rails stuff. so i just skip filling up controllers and use grape instead? sounds good. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Grape works on Rack. See https://github.com/dblock/grape-on-rack for an example.